# Find the least residue

Tags: modular-arithmetic

for $125$ mod $13$ and $-43$ mod $7$

$13$ goes into $125$ $9$ times with a remainder of $8$

$7$ goes into $-43$ $6$ times with a remainder of $1$

So the least residues are $8$ and $1$(possibly $-1$)? Is it really that easy?

Comment: You seem to have ignored the minus sign in $-43$. The remainder is always some $r$ with $0\leqslant r < d$, where $d$ is the divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-43=-7\times7+6,$ so $-43\bmod 7=6.$

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because the remainder $r$ satisfies $0\leqslant r < d$, where $d$ is the divisor.